# How is the Godot Engine itself structured?

Tags: c++, godot, gdscript

I'm looking into making some changes within the source code of the engine
so I looked at the source code on [github](https://github.com/godotengine/godot) but I'm absolutely clueless to how it's actually made up.

and on the web I couldn't find anything on how the engine *itself* is made, only what it can do.

Several questions come to mind:

1. Where does the main script start from? is it from the [Main::setup()](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/820dd1d0016763cda6177104e66e09c8634150be/main/main.cpp#L189)?
2. What would be the flowchart of how the engine operates?
3. How is the engine UI built? (from a web dev point of view, what is the equivalent HTML for it?)

I'm no advance expert in c++ so even a general abstracted overview  would be really helpful to get started

Comment: See _"...Compiler Explorer is written in Node.js...."_  https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer#developing

Comment: @RichardCritten I don't follow, politely asking, how does this relate to the question?

Comment: You had tagged [C++] but Compler Explorer is written in [Node.js] so the C++ tag was not appropriate and the Node.js tag is.  You might get more help with the correct tags.  Link was to show why I was editing the tags.

Comment: @RichardCritten my apologies I realised that and removed the c++ tag

Comment: Why are we talking about Node.js? Godot build is orchestrated from python using [SCons](https://scons.org) as you can read in the documentation [Introduction to the buildsystem](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/compiling/introduction_to_the_buildsystem.html). It is different for each platform (e.g. you need the JDK for Android). Does Godot have JavaScript? Yes, the build templates for the web. For the web builds it uses Emscripten (to webassembly). Emscripten can target Node.js, but Godot does not do that.

Comment: @RichardCritten I think you got Godot (the game engine OP is talking about) and Godbolt (the Compiler Explorer) mixed up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Godot build is orchestrated from python using [SCons](https://scons.org) as you can read in the documentation [Introduction to the buildsystem](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/compiling/introduction_to_the_buildsystem.html). It is different for each platform (e.g. you need the JDK for Android).

As you are aware, you can find the [Godot source code on github](https://github.com/godotengine/godot). Before going further I need to point out that at the time of writing the master branch of the repository corresponds to the development builds of Godot 4. You might want to change to a different branch depending on the version you want to work on.

*Disclaimer: I'm more familiar with Godot 3 code base.*

Now, not only the build process different for each platform, also are the API bindings, and the entry point. You want to see inside the [platform folder](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/tree/master/platform) for operating system specific code.

For example, the entry point for Windows can be found in [godot_windows.cpp](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/master/platform/windows/godot_windows.cpp) and it looks like this:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    godot_hinstance = hInstance;
    return main(0, nullptr);
}
```

You can follow the logic from there, you will find that ultimately they do some initialization and call the methods `setup` and `start` of the `Main` class. You can find the `Main` class in the aptly named [main folder](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/tree/master/main). Afterwards the platform specific code will enter its main loop, and after it finished it will call the method `cleanup` of the `Main` class, and then release any platform specific stuff.

*By the way, when I say a class is in a folder, I mean there are both the .cpp and .h files.*

The main loop might do other things, but it must call the `iteration` method of the `Main` class. You can see the code computes time, calls into different "servers", dispatches input among other things.

---

We don't a flowchart. Sadly we have to piece together the overarching processes. For example, I've written about what happens when you instance an scene [elsewhere](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/194937/10408). I did also look into `queue_free` which you can find [elsewhere](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/192370/10408).

I'll talk a little further about the main loop below. But first I want to point you to the the diagrams we do have:

- [Architecture diagram](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/cpp/introduction_to_godot_development.html).
- [Inheritance tree](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/cpp/inheritance_class_tree.html).

---

Now, the more familiar part of the main loop is that there must be an instance of the `MainLoop` class. It defines initialization and finalization methods, and also methods to be called on each iteration of the main loop. By default it will be an instance of the `SceneTree` class (which extends the `MainLoop` class), but you can change that in project settings. You can find the `MainLoop` class in the [core/os folder](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/tree/master/core/os) and the `SceneTree` class in the [scene/main folder](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/tree/master/scene/main).

The `SceneTree` class has the means to propagate calls of `_process` and `_physics_process` on the… scene tree, among other things. The `SceneTree` has a `root` object of type `Viewport` (in Godot 4 it is a `Window`, which is a type of `Viewport`). And, as you know, `Viewport` is a type of `Node`, and can have children. The children of the `root` are the autoloads, the current scene, and whatever else you put there… Thus from there down it is `Node`s which I expect you to be more familiar with.

On the other side you have sigletons (actual signletons, not autoloads) including the "servers" and some other static utility classes. If you recall Godot has different rendering backends, which are all behind the façade of a "server" (the `VisualServer` in Godot 3, the `RenderingServer` in Godot 4). *In Godot 3 we had a choice of GLES2 and GLES3 for rendering backend.* And the backends also require bindings which you can find back again in the platform folder.

*Here is where my familiarity with Godot source code runs out: I don't know how the shader pipeline works.*

The UI? Just like everything else, it is rendered with whatever rendering backend is being used. On the web? It will be on a `Canvas` HTML element (on a WebGL context). The HTML? The HTML code of the web build template is configurable too (The Custom HTML shell option on the build export settings) see [Custom HTML page for Web export](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/platform/customizing_html5_shell.html). The build process for the web? it uses Emscripten (to webassembly). *No, there is no Node.js stuff in Godot, just to be clear.*

---

As per making changes, you probably can work on the relevant class. For example if you want to work on the `AnimationPlayer` you can find it on the [scene/animation folder](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/tree/master/scene/animation) and make your changes there without much worry about how the rest of the engine works.

To build the engine, as I said at the start you need SCons. Please see [Compiling](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/compiling/index.html) and follow the steps for your platform from the documentation.

And about getting your changes merged into Godot, you want to start with an issue or a proposal (written by you, or somebody else). Followed by a pull request. Please refer to [Contributing](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/community/contributing/index.html) for the overall process and guidelines to get your changes merged into Godot.

Finally if you are having trouble modifying the engine, you can try the [Godot Contributors Chat](https://chat.godotengine.org/).